# Application for object recognition using kinect

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, kinect, image-recognition, haar-classifier

I am working on a project to recognize objects with the Microsoft Kinect.  I have decided to use Haartraining for recognition of items, for example: an apple.  I obtain a .XML file that I've put my code in.

If I put a grape in front of the Kinect and tell my robot that it is a grape, is there any way to retrain my robot so it can detect both apples and grapes?

Comment: Hi Victor.  You may want to add additional tags to your question.  You are using a Kinect, but you are asking a question that is independent of the hardware.  You will get more help if you tag your questions with the image recognition and software concepts you wanting to use, instead of just the `kinect` hardware tag.  I will try to add some tags that might help, but please update them as you see necessary.

Comment: hey.If I use images of apples in order to be recognized by ANN , so if images contain 2 or more apple ANN tell that images contain apples?? or onnly recognize one object inside images